# Error al intentar consumir Api Rest Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, api

les comento un poco sobre este pequeño problema que estoy teniendo. estoy tratando de consumir un api en js. hasta el momento sale bien. este es el código que estoy utilizando. pero el problema es que al cambiar el link, es decir tratar de consumir un api diferente no obtiene los datos correspondientes, ambas api están funcionando.

Links Api:
http://petstore-demo-endpoint.execute-api.com/petstore/pets/

Links Api:
https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/

```
// Api Rest JavaScript
function getCharacters(done) {

    const results = fetch("https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character");
  
    results
      .then(response => response. json())
      .then(data => {
          done(data)
    });
  
  
  }
  
  getCharacters(data => {
  
      data.results.forEach(element => {
  
        const article = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(/*html*/`
        
        
        <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 col-lg-6 mt-3">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body text-center">
                <!--span class="avatar avatar-xxl bradius cover-image" data-bs-image-src="../assets/images/users/2.jpg" style="background: url(&quot;../assets/images/users/15.jpg&quot;) center center;"></span-->     
                <img class="avatar avatar-xxl bradius cover-image" src="${element.image}" alt="Avatar" center center;">           
                <h4 class="h4 mb-0 mt-3">${element.name}</h4>
                <p class="card-text">${element.gender}</p>
                <p>${element.location.name}</p>
                <div class="row user-social-detail text-center">
                    <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank" class="social-profile me-4 rounded text-center bg-secondary-transparent">
                        <i class="fa fa-google text-secondary"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank" class="social-profile me-4 rounded text-center bg-danger-transparent">
                        <i class="fa fa-facebook text-danger"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://www.twitter.com/" target="_blank" class="social-profile rounded text-center bg-success-transparent">
                        <i class="fa fa-twitter text-success"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
  
  
  
        `);
  
  
          const main = document.querySelector("main");
          main.append(article);
  
  
  
  
      });
  
  
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

La data que necesitas en la segunda api(rickandmorti) esta dentro de data.results.results osea en tu codigo deberias de modificarlo de tal forma que quede así:

```
getCharacters(data => {
  
      data.results.results.forEach(..............
```